# Retrieve inserted row calculated data. SQL Server, .NET table adapter, instead of insert

Tags: .net, sql-server, visual-studio, triggers, tableadapter

I, a non-developer, am trying to build some custom business software using SQL Server and .NET framework. I have tables in the server which self monitor to make sure data rules are followed using the instead of insert heading. the procedure checks if there will be any conflicts and if a user has permission to make a specific change and then either inserts the rows or rejects the transaction.

Well I'm just starting on the .net side of things, trying to insert data and all is well except that when I review the inserted rows, my ID, which is Identity, bigint, true zero (-9123... something) doesn't reflect the inserted ID but instead shows, -1, -2, -3... etc.

Does the instead of insert operation stop SQL Server from returning the updated rows? I'm lost here. I have about 20 tables set up like this and am limited on time to finish. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Table Companies in SQL Server

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Companies]
(
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(-9223372036854775808,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [MainPhone] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [AltPhone] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [BillingAddress] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [ShippingAddress] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [ModifiedBy] [bigint] NULL,
    [LastModified] [datetime2](7) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Companies] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Companies] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_Companies_CompanyName]  
        DEFAULT (N'Not provided') FOR [Name]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Companies] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_Companies_MainPhone]  
        DEFAULT (N'Not provided') FOR [MainPhone]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Companies] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_Companies_AltPhone]  
        DEFAULT (N'Not provided') FOR [AltPhone]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Companies] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_Companies_BillingAddress]  
        DEFAULT (N'Not provided') FOR [BillingAddress]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Companies] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_Companies_ShippingAddress]  
        DEFAULT (N'Not provided') FOR [ShippingAddress]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Companies] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_Companies_Editor]  
        DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [ModifiedBy]
GO
```

Instead of insert trigger on `Companies` table SQL Server:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Trig_Company_BeforeInsert]
ON [dbo].[Companies]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --Check for duplicates entries in the rows being inserted
    DECLARE @int1 int;

    SELECT @int1 = COUNT(*) 
                   FROM 
                       (SELECT inserted.Name, COUNT(*) AS Duplicates 
                        FROM inserted 
                        GROUP BY Name 
                        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) AS sq;

    IF (@int1 > 0)
    BEGIN;
        THROW 51000, 'Duplicate entries detected in rows to be inserted. Transaction was canceled.', 10;
        ROLLBACK
    END;

    -- Make sure the new records don't already exist.
    SELECT @int1 = COUNT(*) 
    FROM
        (SELECT * 
         FROM Companies 
         WHERE Name IN (SELECT Name FROM inserted)) AS sq;

    IF (@int1 > 0)
    BEGIN;
        THROW 51000, 'One or more of the new entries already exist. Transaction was canceled', 10;
        ROLLBACK
    END;

    --Check if the current user exists.
    IF (dbo.USER_CurrentUserIsRegistered() = 0)
    BEGIN;
        THROW 51000, 'Current user not registered. Transaction canceled.', 10;
        ROLLBACK
    END;

    --Check if the current user is allowed to Make new companies
    DECLARE @userid bigint
    SET @userid = dbo.USER_GetCurrent()

    DECLARE @canedit bit

    SELECT @canedit = Users.EditCompanies 
    FROM Users 
    WHERE ID = @userid

    IF @canedit = 0
    BEGIN;
        THROW 51000, 'Current user does not have permission.', 10;
        ROLLBACK
    END;

    --if it passed all the checks then go ahead and record it - being sure to mark the current moment in time and user.
    INSERT INTO Companies (AltPhone, BillingAddress, LastModified, MainPhone, ModifiedBy, [Name], ShippingAddress)
        SELECT 
            AltPhone, BillingAddress, GETDATE(), MainPhone, @userid, [Name], ShippingAddress 
        FROM
            inserted;
END
```

Class for keeping track of old and new ID from imported data:

```
Private Class ComboEntry
    Property OldID As Integer
    Property NewEntry As Object

    Sub New()

    End Sub

    Sub New(_Oldid As Integer, _NewEntry As Object)
        OldID = _Oldid
        NewEntry = _NewEntry
    End Sub
End Class

'comboentry objects for keeping track of old ID and new rows'
Dim ClientComboEntries As New List(Of ComboEntry)

'adapters'
Dim ADP_Companies As New JBADevDataSetTableAdapters.CompaniesTableAdapter
Dim TBL_Companies As New JBADevDataSet.CompaniesDataTable
```

My current import Code. Pausing execution and exploring state of rows in table shows the -1 ID'

```
Private Sub ImportClients()
    'setup connection with old database table'
    Dim oldClientAdp As New MTGJobBook2DataSetTableAdapters.EPI_ClientsTableAdapter
    Dim OldClienttble As MTGJobBook2DataSet.EPI_ClientsDataTable = oldClientAdp.GetData()

    Console.WriteLine("")
    Console.WriteLine("Starting import")
    Console.WriteLine(OldClienttble.Count.ToString & " Clients to be added.")

    'initially fill the insert table'
    ADP_Companies.Fill(tbl_Companies)

    Dim Row_Companies As JBADevDataSet.CompaniesRow

    'loop through each old company row and insert'
    For Each r As MTGJobBook2DataSet.EPI_ClientsRow In OldClienttble.Rows
        'Add a new row to the companies table for insert'
        Row_Companies = tbl_Companies.NewCompaniesRow()


        With Row_Companies
            If r.IsPhoneNumber_AltNull Then
                .AltPhone = "PhoneNotProvided"
            Else
                .AltPhone = r.PhoneNumber_Alt
            End If
            If r.IsAddress_BillingNull Then
                .BillingAddress = "Billing address not provided"
            Else
                .BillingAddress = r.Address_Billing
            End If
            If r.IsPhoneNumber_MainNull Then
                .MainPhone = "Main Phone not provided"
            Else
                .MainPhone = r.PhoneNumber_Main
            End If
            If r.IsNameNull Then
                .Name = "Client ID " & r.ClientID.ToString
            Else
                .Name = r.Name
            End If
            If r.IsAddress_ShippingNull Then
                .ShippingAddress = "Shipping Address not provided"
            Else
                .ShippingAddress = r.Address_Shipping
            End If
        End With

        'add the row to the update table'
        tbl_Companies.AddCompaniesRow(Row_Companies)
        'Have to get the row from the table after insert in order' to retain reference to tbl_companies row object
        ClientComboEntries.Add(New ComboEntry(r.ClientID, tbl_Companies.Rows(tbl_Companies.Rows.Count - 1)))
    Next
    Dim insertedcnt As Integer
    Try
        insertedcnt = ADP_Companies.Update(tbl_Companies)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
    Console.WriteLine(insertedcnt.ToString & " rows inserted")
    If Not TBL_Companies.HasErrors Then
        MessageBox.Show("success")
        'add notes for each entry'
        'add contacts'
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Client insert failed.")
    End If
```

Also, like I said, I'm a non-developer so constructive criticism about what I'm doing here in general is also welcome.

Thank you in advance for your time.

I've tried finding the answers by searching online but mostly it seems like the people having this issue are using stored procedures or referencing the wrong property when looking up the ID.

Comment: Well I just tried adding: Select top(x) * from companies order by id DESC. to the trigger and that seems to be working for now but if that could cause some king of issue in the future - I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you were getting negative numbers is because your ID is defined as

```sql
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(-9223372036854775808,1) NOT NULL,
```

so it starts from that number. You probably want this instead

```sql
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
```

---

I'm not sure why you are using an `INSTEAD OF` trigger, but it's completely unnecessary. `INSTEAD OF` triggers have many problematic side effects, and you should avoid them if possible.

If you want to enforce uniqueness on `Name`, just use a proper `UNIQUE` constraint.

```sql
ALTER TABLE Companies
ADD CONSTRAINT uq_Name UNIQUE (Name);
```

To enforce user permissions, SQL Server has a complex system of database, schema, table and column level permissions for each user and role. You should use that instead.

Now, to return the results of the inserte data, do *not* use `select top (1)` as it is unreliable. Instead use `OUTPUT`. For example, if you have an `IDENTITY` column, you can get it back like this

```sql
INSERT YourTable (SomeColumn1, SomeColumn2)
OUTPUT inserted.IdColumn
VALUES (SomeVal1, SomeVal2);
```

---

If you *really really* wanted to use a trigger to enforce permissions, I would advise an `AFTER` trigger.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Trig_Company_BeforeInsert]
ON [dbo].[Companies]
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --Check if the current user exists.
    IF (dbo.USER_CurrentUserIsRegistered() = 0)
    BEGIN;
        THROW 51000, 'Current user not registered. Transaction canceled.', 10;
    END;

    --Check if the current user is allowed to Make new companies
    DECLARE @userid bigint
    SET @userid = dbo.USER_GetCurrent()

    IF (
        SELECT u.EditCompanies 
        FROM Users u
        WHERE u.ID = @userid)
    BEGIN;
        THROW 51000, 'Current user does not have permission.', 10;
    END;
END
```

`ROLLBACK` is unnecessary, as `THROW` will automatically do that for you.

Comment: That is very useful information, Thank you. My biggest reason for using the before insert statement is due to the existence of certain tables where every user can view all rows but only the original user or a user with special permissions can alter the row. The second largest reason was to add the user that performed an update or insert to a column along with a timestamp. I'm under a time crunch so am probably going to move forwarded with the "instead of" but will try to rebuild later with better practices.  Thank you very much for you answer.

Comment: You can use Row Level Security for that. Alternatively a view using the `WITH CHECK OPTION` clause. Either way an `instead of` is not necessary. To add information, you can use `DEFAULT` clauses on those columns.